# What is the definition of these arduino commands, and how do they affect the circuit?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, analogread, analogwrite, map

I don't know if I am allowed to ask this question because really I could just look this up on google. The reason I'm asking here is because in google when you look up the definitions for the following commands, they treat you like you have good knowledge of arduino boards work. I however want to be treated as a beginner who just started learning arduino boards.

So I want to know the definitions of the following commands in a way that I could learn and teach new beginners without getting them confused.

So I want to know the clear definitions of these following commands:

**analogWrite and also why does it have a limit of 255? what does this 255 mean?**

**analogRead  and also why does this have a limit of 1023? what does this mean?**

**digitalWrite and also how does this differ from analogWrite?**

**digitalRead and also how does this differ from analogRead?**

**Loop and setup also what is the void before it?**

**Variables and also how they are declared?**

**Map and also what does it map and how?**

**Serial.write and also how does this differs from analogWrite and digitalWrite?**

**If/else commands and when they should and shouldn't be used?**

Like I said, I do not know whether the question is appropriate, but could be helpful to all the beginners learning Arduino.

Comment: It strikes me that you need to read some basic "Introduction to C programming" tutorials.

Comment: @Majenko Having basic instructions in this site could help too, even if it might not be the first go-to place to learn about arduino's. The answer provided below is clear, short and simple to understand, which is what beginners look towards.

Comment: This site is not the place for basic tutorials. There's already plenty of them around if you just google. Most of your questions can be answered by first learning the basics of the C syntax, which seems to be the information you are lacking to make sense of everything else.

Comment: "I could just look this up on google". Yes, you could.

Comment: I would recommend the Arduino on-line reference and tutorials. Please see https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/HomePage and explore the Learning menu.

Comment: These are reasonable questions, but Stack Exchange is not designed as a tutorial site. The intention is to ask a **specific** question (eg. "can I use a mousetrap to catch a rat?") and not a really general question (eg. "Please describe all the ways I can catch rats").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are a lot of different questions. However, you can find most of the Arduino related answers in the official reference:
[Arduino reference Guide](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage)

Some other answers:

- how to declare variables:

e.g.

```
int x;
```

SerialWrite sends data to the serial port/UART, analogWrite and digitalWrite puts a voltage to a pin (simplified).

AnalogWrite is normally used for a value that has a range (like the intensity of a led), digitalWrite for an On/Off state (can also be for a led but just on/off).

if/else commands can be used to make a program make a decision.

e.g.

```
if (a == 10)
{ 
    Serial.println("10");
}
else
{
    Serial.println("Not 10");
}
```

void means 'nothing' ... in principle it means the functions (setup and loop) do not return any value. You can also define functions which return a value, e.g.

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Read in any C/C++ manual about the commands, get a beginner programmers handbook.

The limit of a pin, means the value cannot be more than 255 or 1023. This means that the range of the value you can get/set is between 0 and 255 or 1023.
The map command can be used to make a value within the range required.

Comment: short, simple, understandable and easy to remember. Thank you. Quick question about something, what do you mean the limit of a "pen"?, what is a 'pen'? is there a reason why they have limits?

Comment: @Utsave: you are welcome ... and I meant pin, not pen (I updated the answer). The main reason is that it has to be mapped to a value usable for computers. In practice e.g. a voltage can be anything from 0.00000 to 5.0000 V for example. However, computers use bits/bytes and it is not useful to keep 10 significant digts. With 1024 (0-1023 values) the accuracy is good enough and 1024 is 10 bits (2 to the power 10).